# App doesn't build on my device

Tags: xcode, build, device

The app I am working on runs perfectly in the simulator, on an iPad, and on an iPhone. When I try to run it on my iPod Touch, NOTHING HAPPENS...

Xcode says "Building..."
and then it says "Finished running"

Nothing is written to the console and the app icon isn't installed on the iPod Touch and the app never even attempts to run.

Any ideas what could possibly be going wrong would be greatly appreciated. If there was some error that came up that would at least be helpful, but nothing happens whatsoever.

Thanks so much!

**EDIT: I've gone back and opened some of my previously finished apps and all of them do this same thing when I try to run them on the iPod Touch...**

*Could this have anything to do with my having upgraded to XCode 4.2 and the iPod Touch still running OS 3.1.3?  The deployment target in Build Settings is still 3.1.3 and up, so I don't think it should be an issue...*

Comment: In the drop-down in top of X-Code does it mention a specific iPod or just say iOS device?

Comment: Thanks Jamund - yes, it does show my actual device name. I have used it for development before on other apps but now it is not working...    =(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The armv6 architecture needed to be added to the build settings in order for me to build to the iPod Touch (OS 3.1.3).

In Xcode 4.2, in the Build Settings, under Architectures, armv6 wasn't an option for me in the dropdown menu. I had to select "Other...", then use the + sign to manually type in "armv6" NOT IN PLACE OF but IN ADDITION TO what was already entered there, which was "$(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT)" and then I was able to build my app to the iPod Touch.

As a final note - while I got the app to run on my iPod Touch OS 3.1.3, it did not run as well as I wanted it to (as well as it runs on the iPad OS 5 and iPhone OS 4.2) so while I've previously always supported OS 3.1 in my apps, I sadly ended up NOT supporting armv6 for this one and setting the iOS Deployment Target for my app to iOS 3.2

Answer (score 1):

Does your scheme target dropdown list show "iOS Device" or does it show the "name" of your iPod Touch (something like "jons ipod touch"):

[image: Scheme Target]

If it shows "iOS Device", that means your iPod isnt recognized by xcode and you may need to enable the device for developing by clicking "*Use For Development*" like so:

[image: Enable For Development]

Comment: Thanks chown - yes, it does show my actual device name. I have used it for development before on other apps.

Comment: @ObjectiveFlash Try checking the settings for the device scheme then, you may not have one of the specific task options enabled (like "run").